# Masking text file

Tags: c#, text

I writing a c# application that masking a text files. I have a large text file encoded with `UTF-8`. I want to present only part of this file. All the other text will be masked with "*" character (replace the old character that I want to hide). So, let's assume that:

1. The text file contains 1000 character.
2. We want to mask those ranges: 0-100, 200-1000. What's mean, the section of 100-200 will be clear (unmasked, real text).

This is how the method signature should looks like:

```
public void Mask(MemoryStream inputData, int clearSectionStart, int clearSectionEnd)
{
}
```

### Target 1 - Beginners:

The requested output is the masked file. I should run all over the masked section (e.g. section 0-100 and 200-1000) and replace those characters with "*".

For example, if the text file content will be "Hello world" and I want to keep the word "world" unmasked (6-11), the expected output will be:

> ******world

### Target 2 - Advanced:

Exactly like target 1, but now we should keep the sentence format like the original. That's mean, we will keep the unmasked section and also keep those characters unmasked:

- ' '
- '.'
- ','

For this input: "Hello, bot." + clear section 7-10 ("bot") -> the expected output will be:

> *****, bot.

### Possible solutions?

I wondering how should I solve this problem.

The first naive option is to read all the text from the file to stream and working on this string to hide parts of it. This, of cause, this most slow solution and also include high amount of available RAM in case of long text file.

Another possible solution is to implement a custom stream reader that will read the source stream (the text file) and manipulate the content to hide parts of the stream.

What do you think is the best way? any advice\solution will be helpful.

Comment: Why don't you start on it and ask a question when you've actually got an answerable question? _"Show me all the pros and cons of my proposed solutions"_ (pardon any interpretation error) is a tad too broad to answer, if not opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

you could read one character at once and check for the index you want and length you need to get text portion you need.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
     class Program
     {
           static void Main(string[] args)
           {
                var maskedString  = MaskFileContent(@"C:\PSQL_v10_Install.log", 100, 200);
                Console.WriteLine(maskedString);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            static string MaskFileContent(string filePath, int indexOfClearData, int lengOfClearData, string mask ="***")
            {
                 int counter = 0;
                 StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

                 System.IO.StreamReader file =
                            new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath);
                 while (!file.EndOfStream)
                 {
                      var curChar = (char)file.Read();
                      if (counter >= indexOfClearData)
                      {
                          result.Append(curChar.ToString());
                      }

                      if(result.Length >= lengOfClearData)
                           break;

                      counter++;
                }

                file.Close();
                result.Insert(0, mask);
                result.Append(mask);

                return result.ToString();
          }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this without loading all of the data into memory by using a buffer to read, mask and write the data in chunks.

```
public class TextMasker
{
    private readonly int _bufferSize;
    private readonly string _outputDataPath;
    private readonly byte _maskByte;
    private readonly byte[] _unmaskableBytes;

    public TextMasker()
    {
        _bufferSize = 4096;
        _outputDataPath = "outputData.txt";
        _maskByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("*")[0];
        _unmaskableBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(" ,.");
    }

    public void Mask(MemoryStream inputData, int unmaskedStart, int unmaskedStop)
    {
        var byteIndex = 0;
        var buffer = new byte[_bufferSize];

        using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(_outputDataPath))
        {
            int bytesBuffered;
            while ((bytesBuffered = inputData.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < bytesBuffered; i++, byteIndex++)
                {
                    if ((byteIndex < unmaskedStart - 1 || byteIndex > unmaskedStop - 1)
                        && !_unmaskableBytes.Contains(buffer[i]))
                    {
                        buffer[i] = _maskByte;
                    }
                }

                fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesBuffered);
            }
        }
    }
}
```